# Adding a link in post-type list

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, add-filter

I want to add a custom link in the posts of my post-type with the filter *post_row_actions* but there's no additional link.

I use this code :

```
function custom_duplicate_link( $actions, $post ) {
    $actions['duplicate'] = '<a href="admin.php?action=custom_duplicate_post_as_draft&amp;post=' . $post->ID . '" title="Duplicate" rel="permalink">Duplicate</a>';
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'custom_duplicate_link', 10, 2 );
```

Have I missed anything? Or does anyone know why it isn't working?

Comment: what is actual purpose??

Comment: I want to duplicate a custom post type like event to antoher custom post type

Answer (score 1):

Check your custom post type:

'hierarchical' => TRUE,

1. The filter 'post_row_actions' only work with post types not hierarchical.
2. The filter 'page_row_actions' only work with post types hierarchical.

Comment: Thank you : I found the solution but I didn't update the topic